# How to tell openmp not to synchronize an array

Tags: c, linux, gcc, openmp, x86-64

I have a code that has the following structure.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    .....
    index = get_index(...);
    array[index] = ...;
    .....
}
```

Now the value of `index` is unique for each thread (it never gets overlapped for different threads), but of course OpenMP can't make a guess for this and I suppose is using synchronization objects to access `array`.

How can I ask openmp not to use synchronization objects for `array` and rely on me that `index` value is unique for different threads. I try to put `array` in private list, but got segmentation fault for that.

Comment: OpenMP does not synchronize anything by default. So that shouldn't be a problem. Is `index` declared inside or outside the parallel region?

Comment: FYI: writing to a shared array from different threads can lead to horrendous performance issues, due to cache trashing. You should make sure that there is some distance between the indeces currently written by those threads).

Answer (score 6):

Openmp does synchronize at barriers or implicit barriers. For example, there is an implicit barrier at the end of a `for` construct unless a nowait clause is specified.

But openmp does not synchronize memory by access for you. Instead, it provides mechanisms for shared and private memory blocks for each thread.

In your case, `index` needs to be private. Otherwise each thread writes to the same memory location and you will have a race condition, when you access `array[index]`.

For demonstration, I set the behavior explicitly, although `i` is private by default and `array` shared by default.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, index) shared(array)
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    .....
    index = get_index(...);
    array[index] = ...;
    .....
}
```